# cx_freeze Matplotlib issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, cx-freeze, python-exec

There seems to be a few people who are struggling to build Python executables that use the Matplotlib library.

I am using CX_Freeze and can create a executable for my GUI without the graphs, but when the graphs with the matplolib library are added, when I try to run the executable I get error:

```
from .import _methods ImportError: cannot import name '_methods'
```

Has anyone managed to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your setup.py file:

**addtional_mods = ['numpy.core._methods']**